# Python issue with database conditioning

Tags: python, mongodb

I am a beginner in python. I am trying to connect to a database and match user entered values.

```
if staff==<user entered value>and paper==<user entered value>:
   test=db.staff.find({"staff":<user entered value>,"paper":<user entered value>})
   print(test.get('staff'))
   print(test.get('paper'))
```

if test has no value,I get error when the database returns no value

Comment: It seems like you are using mongodb. Right?

Comment: yes , I am using mongodb

Comment: from where do you get the value of staff in the first place?

Comment: staff is the overall collection of all the staff

Answer (score 1):

- You should use the [**`.count`**](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count) to check if your query returns any result.
- [**`.find`**](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) returns an instance of [**`Cursor`**](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor) so you have to loop over your query result.

  ```
  if staff==<user entered value>and paper==<user entered value>:
      test = db.staff.find({"staff":<user entered value>,"paper":<user entered value>})
      if(test.count()):
          for doc in test:
              print(test['staff'])
              print(test['paper'])
  ```

If `staff` and `paper` are unique in your collection use the [**`find_one`**](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) method.

```
if staff==<user entered value>and paper==<user entered value>:
    test = db.staff.find_one({"staff":<user entered value>,"paper":<user entered value>})
    if(test):
        print(test['staff'])
        print(test['paper'])
```

Answer (score 1):

When your `db.staff.find_one({"staff":<user entered value>,"paper":<user entered value>})` doesn't match anything in your database the value of `test` will be `None`. And a None object does not have a `.get()` method.

You may need to use an if statement to check it before running `.get()` method

Comment: This will fail because [`.find`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor) returns a cursor not document

Comment: His question was about dealing with empty test. In your case he can loop over the cursor or use find_one()